# How to control the file num in Delta Lake merge output

Tags: apache-spark, partition, delta-lake

I'm using Delta Lake 0.4.0 with Merge like:

```
target.alias("t")
          .merge(
            src.as("s"),
            "s.id = t.id 
          )
          .whenMatched().updateAll()
          .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
          .execute()
```

src reads from a folder with thousands of files. The merge results generate many small files too. Is there a way to control the file number in merge results like effect of repartition(1) or coalesce(1)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to control the number of files in a Delta output operation. Instead, use `OPTIMIZE` at the appropriate time or, on platforms such as Databricks, take advantage of [auto-optimization](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/auto-optimize.html).

Comment: hmm, we are using open source delta lake, so we cannot use that, right? We load small real-time data files to delta lake. We expect to avoid another compression. Maybe we have to split the merge to update and insert by ourselves.

Comment: If you split it, you'd lose atomicity, which is the key feature of Delta. I'd strongly recommend against it. You can run OPTIMIZE on a schedule.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about the atomicity. Say we do update first and then insert. If update succeeded but insert failed, next time it will do update and insert again for the same data. It should be idempotent (need to fully test this). The thing is with merge, for 500 files (around 1GB), it generates many small files ~4MB. Not sure optimize works for open source delta lake.

Comment: The issue with atomicity is that between the update and the insert the table is an in inconsistent state and, unless you take explicit steps to prevent it, via the nature of how you solve the problem, via a workflow server or a (cross-cluster) locking system, an operation can use that inconsistent state. In other words, without atomicity, idempotency is only guaranteed assuming a specific order of operations, which you have to ensure. When you have atomicity, you don't have to worry about order of operations. (Idempotency is always the way to go.)

Comment: Hi Sim, auto-optimization you mentioned is not in open source delta lake yet, right? I tried to add spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled and spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled, but seems not take effect.

Comment: Yup, saw that. If you can pause stream writes you can rewrite the table using `df.repartition()` and Delta's ACID I/O. That's manual compaction.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#performance-tuning  you can now set spark.delta.merge.repartitionBeforeWrite to true for avoiding that.